# How to pass EMR cluster ID in the CloudWatch Alarm

Tags: yaml, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-emr, amazon-data-pipeline

I am trying to create a SNS alarm for my EMR cluster so when EMR cluster is failed i should get notified .

But my issue is i am not able to pass Cluster ID as JobFlowId in the CloudWatch Alarm .

I am create all resources using CloudFomartion Templet .

When i use REF to refer Cluster Id i get below error .

```
Error
Template validation error: Template format error: Unresolved resource dependencies [FinancialLineItemEmrCluster] in the Resources block of the template
```

Here is my templet .

I am having issue specially in at `JobFlowId` while creating the resources `EMRAlarm`

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Description: TRF SDI Optmization Full File  Creation

Parameters:
  AppName:
    Default: trfsdioptmization
    Description: trfsdioptmization.
    Type: String
  Environment:
    Type: String
    Default: nonprod
  FinancialIdentifier:
    Type: String
    Default: 123456789
  ApplicationAssetInsightId:
    Type: String
    Default: 12345678
  EnvironmentType:
    Type: String
    AllowedValues:
      - "prod"
      - "PRE-PRODUCTION"
      - "QUALITY ASSURANCE"
      - "nonprod"
    Default: nonprod
  ResourceOwner:
    Type: String
    Default: sudarshan.kumar@abcd.com
  EnvironmentPhase:
    Type: String
    Default: nonprod
  RegionAbbreviation:
    Default: us-east-1
    Description: Region Abbreviation e.g. us-east-1 for us-east
    Type: String

Resources:
 TRFSDIFullfileGeneration: 
  Type: "AWS::DataPipeline::Pipeline"
  #DeletionPolicy: Retain
  Properties: 
    Name: !Sub "${ApplicationAssetInsightId}-tr-fr-${EnvironmentPhase}-${RegionAbbreviation}-${AppName}-DataPipeline"
    Description: "Pipeline to create full file for TRFSDI full file Optmization"
    Activate: false
    PipelineObjects: 
      - 
        Id: "FinancialLineItemActivity"
        Name: "FinancialLineItemActivity"
        Fields: 
          - 
            Key: "type"
            StringValue: "EmrActivity"
          - 
            Key: "runsOn"
            RefValue: "FinancialLineItemEmrCluster"
          - 
            Key: "step"
            StringValue: "command-runner.jar,spark-submit,--master,yarn-cluster,--deploy-mode,cluster,--class,start.EntryFileCreation,s3://205147-trf-fr-nonprdo-us-east-1-trfsdioptmization/AJAR/SparkJob-0.1-jar-with-dependencies.jar,FinancialLineItem"

        Id: "Default"
        Name: "Default"
        Fields: 
          - 
            Key: "type"
            StringValue: "Default"
          - 
            Key: "scheduleType"
            StringValue: "ONDEMAND"
          - 
            Key: "failureAndRerunMode"
            StringValue: "CASCADE"
          - 
            Key: "role"
            StringValue: "DataPipelineDefaultRole"
          - 
            Key: "resourceRole"
            StringValue: "DataPipelineDefaultResourceRole"
          - 
            Key: "pipelineLogUri"
            StringValue: "s3://205147-tr-fr-nonprod-us-east-1-trfsdioptmization/EMRLOGS"
      - 
        Id: "FinancialLineItemEmrCluster"
        Name: "FinancialLineItemEmrCluster"
        Fields: 
          - 
            Key: "terminateAfter"
            StringValue: "30 Minutes"
          - 
            Key: "releaseLabel"
            StringValue: "emr-5.9.0"
          - 
            Key: "masterInstanceType"
            StringValue: "m3.xlarge"
          - 
            Key: "coreInstanceType"
            StringValue: "m3.2xlarge"
          - 
            Key: "coreInstanceCount"
            StringValue: "2"
          - 
            Key: "type"
            StringValue: "EmrCluster"
          - 
            Key: "applications"
            StringValue: "spark"
          - 
            Key: "subnetId"
            StringValue: "subnet-86febcab"
          - 
            Key: "onSuccess"
            RefValue: "FinancialLineItem_Success"
          - 
            Key: "onFail"
            RefValue: "FinancialLineItem_Fail"
 EMRAlarm:
   Type: AWS::CloudWatch::Alarm
   Properties:
    AlarmDescription: "Raise alarm if apps running on EMR cluster is killed"
    Namespace: AWS/ElasticMapReduce
    MetricName: AppsKilled
    Dimensions:
    - Name: 205147-TRFSDIOPTmization
      JobFlowId: !Ref FinancialLineItemEmrCluster
    Statistic: Average
    Period: 15
    EvaluationPeriods: '1'
    ComparisonOperator: GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold
    Threshold: 1
    AlarmActions:
    - "AWSTRF_HEALTH"
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no resource of the type `AWS::EMR::Cluster` in your template. 
You are referencing something called `FinancialLineItemEmrCluster` in your CloudWatch Alarm. From the context, I am assuming you are trying to reference a EMR job. However, since you have no parameter or resource in your template named `FinancialLineItemEmrCluster`, you can not access is.

EMR cluster IDs generally look like this: `j-1ABCD123AB1A`. You have several options:

If this cluster is in another template, you could create a [CloudFormation export](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-cfn-stack-exports.html) in that stack, and use [`!ImportValue`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-importvalue.html) in your template to import it.

Alternatively, you could use a Parameter in your template and pass the ClusterId that way. Add this as a parameter:

Example:

```
 FinancialLineItemEmrCluster:
    Description: 'Your EMR cluster id. Example: j-1ABCD123AB1A'
    Type: String
```

A third alternative is  to just hardcode it into your template.

In any case, you can not refer directly to a resource in another stack.

If you have not createt an EMR::Cluster at all, and have no Cluster Id, you need to create one first. You could add one to your Template using the [`AWS::EMR::Cluster`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-emr-cluster.html) resource:

```
FinancialLineItemEmrCluster: 
  Type: AWS::EMR::Cluster
  Properties: 
    Instances: 
      MasterInstanceGroup: 
        InstanceCount: 1
        InstanceType: "m3.xlarge"
        Market: "ON_DEMAND"
        Name: "Master"
      CoreInstanceGroup: 
        InstanceCount: 2
        InstanceType: "m3.xlarge"
        Market: "ON_DEMAND"
        Name: "Core"
      TerminationProtected: true
    Name: "TestCluster"
    JobFlowRole: "EMR_EC2_DefaultRole"
    ServiceRole: "EMR_DefaultRole"
    ReleaseLabel: "emr-4.2.0"
```

Comment: Yes i am creating EMR cluster using Data Pipeline that is why i am not getting exact ID to pass ...

Comment: In that case, you most likely want to use a parameter. I have updated my answer to include an example.

Comment: Answer is useful but has not solved my problem ...I am passing as paramter but still getting same issue ...To pass as parameter do i have to create Cluster first? Sorry i am new to YAML...

Comment: This is something your need to include in your initial question. In any case, I updated my answer to reflect that.